# Google mock wrong expectation

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, googletest, googlemock

Today I had google mock warning about an uninteresting mock function call, the problem is it warns about a method that is not mocked.

Providing you some context:

```
 protected:
  virtual boost::future<bool> write(std::string rawMessage) = 0;
  virtual bool readHandler(const std::string& message) = 0;

 public:
  void read() {
    asio::spawn(_strand, [this](asio::yield_context yield) {
      _isReading = true;
      while (!_stopRequested) {
        asio::deadline_timer yielder(_strand.get_io_service());
        auto future = _streamController->read();

        while (!future.is_ready()) {
          this->timedYield(yielder, yield, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1));
        }
        this->readHandler(future.get().data());
      }
      _isReading = false;
    });
  }
```

write and readHandler are the two methods that are mocked, read is the method gmock complains about.

My mock is:

```
class Client : public Protocol::Client<Adapter> {
 public:
  Client(asio::io_service& ioService, std::unique_ptr<Adapter> adapter,
         std::shared_ptr<Infra::Network::Mock::StreamController> streamController)
    : Protocol::Client<Adapter>(ioService, std::move(adapter), std::move(streamController)) {}

  MOCK_METHOD1(write, boost::future<bool>(std::string rawMessage));
  MOCK_METHOD1(readHandler, bool(const std::string& message));
};
```

The exact message is:

```
GMOCK WARNING: Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
    Function call: read()
          Returns: 16-byte object <00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00> NOTE: You can safely ignore the above warning unless this call should not happen.  Do not suppress it by blindly adding an EXPECT_CALL() if you don't mean to enforce the call.
```

I'm using the version 1.8.0 of gtest.

Do you have any idea why this error occurs and how should I solve it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `Infra::Network::Mock::StreamController`? Maybe it has `read()`?

Comment: Thank you for opening my eyes ....